# Getting a wrong count for a text file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the row count for a text file using Pshell. I have used queries such as:

```
$count = 0
$reader = New-Object IO.StreamReader $Filename
while($reader.ReadLine() -ne $null){ $count++ }
$reader.Close()
```

or

```
$measure = Get-Content $Filename| Measure-Object 
$lines = $measure.Count
```

but getting a wrong row count for only one specific text file.It is actually returning a slihgly bigger count than it should.

If I use the below command in cmd though, I'll get the correct count:

```
set file=E:\A.txt
set /a cnt=0
for /f %%a in ('type "%file%"^|find "" /v /c') do set /a cnt=%%a
echo %cnt%
```

Can someone help me to translate this to Powershell?
I do very much appreciate your help and advice in advance.

Comment: Do these two commands produce different output? `(Get-Content "problemtextfile.txt" | Measure-Object).Count` vs. `(cmd /c type "problemtextfile.txt" | Measure-Object).Count` (of course, specify your problem text file as the parameter)

Comment: Yes ran them, and they return the same (slightly bigger) number.

Comment: Both commands return the same count? Look at your "problem" text file in a plain-text editor such as Notepad and go to the end of the file. What is the line number? It should be the same as the PowerShell command says.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really sure but I think that your original script is counting only non-empty lines, and maybe that's the reason why the powershell version is bigger.

Try with this script and check if it's ok:

```
Get-Content $Filename | Select-String "." | measure -line
```

Regards